# SQL query on columns of a table....(Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables say (`FCT_SALES_SUMMARY_A` and `FCT_SALES_SUMMARY_B`).

If we assume that `table A` has be generated on every Monday than `table B` will be generated on next Monday 
i.e after 1 week like that there will be data for 104 weeks. But the as the weeks increase the previous data 
will be lost in `FCT_SALES_SUMMARY_A`  as shown below i.e the `col104` in `table B` will have the data of that week and the 
`table A` will loose the first `col1` data.

As shown below some times the data for the same week in both the tables will be different.
for example the salary for the week 22nd jan has been changed in `FCT_SALES_SUMMARY_B`.

Now I need to find out the changed data for the same week comparing the columns in both tables.
i.e, the `col2` in `FCT_SALES_SUMMARY_A` should be compared with `col1` in `FCT_SALES_SUMMARY_B`.

For example the data in tables is in columns:

```
Table A
col:col1........col2........col3........col4........col5...col104
WEEk:1stjan......8thjan......15thjan.....22ndjan.....
sal:100.........200.........300.........400.........


TABLE B

col:col1........col2........col3........col4........col5...col104
WEEk:8thjan......15thjan.....22thjan.....29ndjan.....
sal:200.........300.........450.........500.........
```

---

Table is defined as follow.s:

```
DESC FCT_SALES_SUMMARY


CREATE TABLE FCT_SALES_SUMMARY
(
  PROD_SID                 NUMBER,
  CURR_CUST_SID            NUMBER,
  BIO_ID                   NUMBER,
  CURR_TERR_SID            NUMBER,
  FRAN_SID                 NUMBER,
  CURR_EMP_SID             NUMBER,
  ESTMT_FLG                VARCHAR2(1 BYTE),
  PROD_WAC_PRC             NUMBER(15,4),
  SALE_RATIO               NUMBER,
  WK_UNITSCUR              NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS1                NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS2                NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS3                NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS4                NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS5                NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS6                NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS7                NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS8                NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS9                NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS10               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS11               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS12               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS13               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS14               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS15               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS16               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS17               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS18               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS19               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS20               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS21               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS22               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS23               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS24               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS25               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS26               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS27               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS28               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS29               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS30               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS31               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS32               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS33               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS34               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS35               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS36               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS37               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS38               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS39               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS40               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS41               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS42               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS43               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS44               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS45               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS46               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS47               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS48               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS49               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS50               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS51               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS52               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS53               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS54               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS55               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS56               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS57               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS58               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS59               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS60               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS61               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS62               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS63               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS64               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS65               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS66               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS67               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS68               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS69               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS70               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS71               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS72               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS73               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS74               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS75               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS76               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS77               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS78               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS79               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS80               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS81               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS82               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS83               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS84               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS85               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS86               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS87               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS88               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS89               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS90               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS91               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS92               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS93               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS94               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS95               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS96               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS97               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS98               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS99               NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS100              NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS101              NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS102              NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS103              NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS104              NUMBER(15,4),
  WK_UNITS105              NUMBER(15,4)
```

)

We need to compare data week by week.

Comment: Any reason why your tables are so de-normalized?

Comment: What column in FCT_SALES_SUMMARY represents the date? WK_UNIT1 could infer that it would be Jan 1, but that account for the rolling dates you mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the information given so far, I'd say that [First Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) would be your friend here.

So your table would become something more like this:

```
CREATE TABLE FCT_SALES_SUMMARY
(
  PROD_SID                 NUMBER,
  CURR_CUST_SID            NUMBER,
  BIO_ID                   NUMBER,
  CURR_TERR_SID            NUMBER,
  FRAN_SID                 NUMBER,
  CURR_EMP_SID             NUMBER,
  ESTMT_FLG                VARCHAR2(1 BYTE),
  PROD_WAC_PRC             NUMBER(15,4),
  SALE_RATIO               NUMBER,
  WK_UNITSCUR              NUMBER(15,4),
  WEEK_NUMBER              NUMBER,
  WK_UNITS                 NUMBER(15,4)
)
```

...with one row per week (as designated by WEEK_NUMBER above - call it whatever is most meaningful for your app).

Now you won't lose any data that you don't want to lose: WEEK_NUMBER (or whatever) just keeps incrementing by one each week.

Will it make the table's storage requirements greater? Yes. Disc space is cheap.

Will it make queries slower? Possibly, but computers are fast...  ;-)

Comment: You're assuming the OP has the ability to change the data model.  I've seen accounting programs with similar [horrendous] modelling...

Comment: Yes I am. And I've suffered something ghastly like that myself... But if he can't change the schema, there's no good answer that I can think of - only bad ones. Really, really bad. IOW, if he wanted to get to there, he shouldn't start from here...